# How to get <td> through <tr> id Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I've been trying to get td value through tr id. Usual way I know is by using

```
 document.getelementById("tableID").rows[0].cells.item(2).innerHTML;
```

but problem is my table is dynamic so table rows keep changing through adding and deleting. to overcome this I decided to generate  id through random().
So anyone knows a better way to get a specific  value using JS.

```js
function add(){

    var tbl = document.getElementById("tableID");
    var TrId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
    var tableTR = document.createElement('tr');
    tableTR.id = TrId;
    tbl.appendChild(tableTR);
    
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    switch (i){
    case 0:
    var newelement = document.createElement('td');
    var newbtn = document.createElement('input');
    newbtn.type = "button";
    newbtn.value = "Remove";
    newbtn.id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
    newbtn.onclick =  function() {deletedRow(this)};
    tableTR.appendChild(newelement);
    newelement.appendChild(newbtn);
    break;
    
    case 1:
    var n = document.getElementById('nme').value;
    var newelement = document.createElement('td');
    newelement.innerHTML = n;
    tableTR.appendchild(newelement);
    break;
    
    case 2:
    var n = document.getElementById('snme').value;
    var newelement = document.createElement('td');
    newelement.innerHTML = n;
    tableTR.appendchild(newelement);
    break;
    }
    }
    
}

function deletedRow(btn){

    var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
    
    document.getElementById('here').innerText = "get surname"

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<label>Name<input id="nme" value="" style="width: 40%;"></label>
<label>surname<input id="snme" value="" style="width: 40%;"></label>
<br><br>
<input type="button" id="click" onclick="add();" value="Add"/>
<table id="tableID">
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Age</td>
</tr>
</table>

<p id="here"></p>
//I want the surname to be placed here upon deleting a row
</body>
</html>
```

Don't mind it not working. I was just hoping this will give you an idea of what I'm really working on.

Comment: Which `<td>` are you trying to get? Also, you mentioned random but I'm not sure where it applies to - are you trying to get a random cell or assign a random value?

Comment: Show us the final html result and indicate what you want to get out of it

Answer (score 0):

By getting the ID of the tr through the button by using parentNode, we can just easily create a for loop through using rows.length . adding an if statement checking whether the current row id in the length equals to that of the known tr id. Henceforth since we already got to the desired row in the loop and we already in the if statement might as well just use the known method :`document.getElementById("printTable").rows[i].cells.item(2).innerHTML;`

```
function deletedRow(btn){
var l;
var TrId = btn.parentNode.parentNode.id;
var rws = document.getElementById("tableID").rows;

for( var i = 0; i<rws.length ; i++){    

    if(rws[i].id == TrId){

        l = document.getElementById("printTable").rows[i].cells.item(2).innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('here').innerText= l;
    }
    
}}
```